# Reload/refresh a page in JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, mobile

I'm converting a website into a mobile app, for this I need to get the output as JSON format. Everything works perfectly but the problem is when I add/edit something it and actually updates in table but in JSON output it shows the old values.

For example

```
    result = App::Web::AddAddress.create_edit(
    :controller => self,
    :client => @client,
    :data => @request_data,
    :language => 'en',
    :create => 1
  )
  if result.success == true
    return view_address_list
  end
   rescue
  return fail_request
```

My problem is, if its success its returns to the view_address_list with old values(even though it updates the values in database). If I run the view_address_list again, it shows the updated values and I'm sure I need to refresh/reload the method. Is there any way to reload/refresh the view_address_list method when it returns a success?

Answer (score 1):

I think once you start getting into the development of your mobile app, most of your requests will be sent using AJAX, and you will receive JSON responses, which you can parse and use in your application. As long as you're not caching this response, you will receive new values in each response. This is especially true if you're using jQuery Mobile (A popular choice), which is heavily based on AJAX requests.

A quick (fake) way to work with your response

```
//...
success: function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, address) {
    address.content.appendTo('#list');
  });
},
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, the thing is that I'm not dealing with front end, only back end, the front end guys wants every output as JSON. I"m not sure whether they use jQuery mobile or not. I really appreciate your help. Is there any way can I reload it in the controller itself?

Comment: @jens not without access to the frontend, no. The front end guy should know how to do AJAX request/response scenarios. If not, find another front end guy :-) In short, this part is not your responsibility